# Custom steps in add to cart functionality in magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, e-commerce, magento-1.9

I am developing a magento store. We need two custom steps during add to cart functionality.
When we click add to cart button for a simple product, we need to open two pages with few selected options. One changing some option Price should be updated.

I am new in magento development. Please help.
Below is what we want.[image]

Step1.[image]

Step2[image]

Step3[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use custom options for the products  Go to

**_admin->catalog->manage Product->[select a product]->custom options**

But for each product you need to add options .
You can have an option for add price for each option and it will automatically reflected in your price.

If the pop up is necessary then you can design the custom option part in to a pop up with design customization.